# Find (ICD9 code) and replace parentheses with |

Tags: regex, notepad++, icd

I'm using Notepad++ v6.9.2. I need to find ICD9 Codes which will take the following forms:

- `(X##.)`, `(X##.#)` or `(X##.##)` where `X` is a letter and always at the beginning and `#` is a number
- `(##.)`, `(##.#)`, `(##.##)`, `(###.)`, `(###.#)`, `(###.##)` or `(###.###)` where `#` is a number

and

replace the first `(` with `|` and the `)` and single space behind second with `|`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
(305.11) TOBACCO ABUSE-CONTINUOUS
```

Becomes:

```
|305.11|TOBACCO ABUSE-CONTINUOUS
```

**OTHER CONSIDERATIONS:**

There are other places with parentheses but will only contain letters. Those do not need to be changed. Some examples:

```
UE (Major) Amputation
(282.45) THALASSEMIA (ALPHA)
(284.87) RED CELL APLASIA (W/THYMOMA)
Pain (non-headache) (338.3) Neoplasm related pain (acute) (chronic)
```

Becomes

```
UE (Major) Amputation
|282.45|THALASSEMIA (ALPHA)
|284.87|RED CELL APLASIA (W/THYMOMA)
Pain (non-headache) |338.3|Neoplasm related pain (acute) (chronic)
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this to match ICD9 codes:

```
[EV]\d+\.?\d*
```

This covers both E and V codes and cases where the `.` is omitted (in my experience this is not uncommon). Use this regex to match the portions of text you need:

```
\(([EV]?\d+\.?\d*)\)\s?
```

The outer parentheses are escaped to match literal `(` and `)` characters, and the inner parentheses create a group for replacement (`\1`). The `\s?` at end will capture an optional space after the parentheses.

So your Notepad++ replace window should look like this:

[image: Notepad++ replace]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for answer and lesson on regex.

Comment: Additionally, after file transformation in Notepad++ I imported the text file into excel. To force the ICD9 codes to be text instead of numeric which loses information I changed the replace statement to:  |'\1\